# Java - Unable to pass 1 dimension array to 2 dimension array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to read a pdf file using pdfbox line by line so that i can compare it with an older version.

For this, i have done:

```
static String[][] SplitString_into_array(String string_to_split)
{
    final int SIZE = 1495; //max size allowed in array
    int number_arrays = string_to_split.length()/SIZE;
    int start = 0;
    int end = SIZE;
    int max = string_to_split.length();
    int i, j;

    // Pdfs are very big, so i had to create a 2d array, 
    // where ROWS are the number of arrays to be created 
    // based on the size and COLS are the max size allowed.

    String[][] pdf_final = new String[number_arrays][SIZE]; 
    String[] pdf_split = new String[SIZE];


    for(i = 0; i < pdf_final.length; i++)
    {
        String tmp  = string_to_split.substring(start, end);

        for(j = 0; j < pdf_final[i].length-1; j++)  
        {        
            pdf_split = tmp.split("\\r?\\n");  
            pdf_final[i][j] = pdf_split[j];
        }

        start = SIZE + 1;            
        end = SIZE + SIZE;

        if(end > max)
        {
            end = max;
        }
    }

    return pdf_final;
}
```

The problem is that i'm getting an error out of bound exception when doing:

```
pdf_final[i][j] = pdf_split[j];
```

It seems that J is only reaching the max size of I, but i have no idea why, since both sizes are defined correctly.

Can someone help me?

Regards

Comment: "It seems that J is only reaching the max size of I, but i have no idea why, since both sizes are defined correctly." Well what do you believe the size of `pdf_split` is? You've assigned it a new value in the line before, so the original assignment at the point of declaration is irrelevant.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by splitting the PDF contents like this? By splitting everything you are actually using at least twice the memory compared to working on the contents directly. Rendering your comment about large PDFs completely meaningless.

Comment: @dpr i had to compare two pdf's line by line and generate an output similar to:                                                                                                        PDF 1   LINE BLABLA  | PDF 2 LINE BLA

Comment: @Jon when i print the size of the arrays i have pdf_split = 1495 and pdf_final should be something like, for example: pdf_final[46][1495]

Comment: Where were you printing the size though? If it's anywhere before the last assignment to `pdf_split`, it's irrelevant. (Aside from anything else, it's very unclear why you're calling `split` in the inner loop - why would you do that on every iteration?)

Comment: @Jon i was just trying to see what was the max value i could set for the array size. i placed the spit before the inner loop, but the result seems the same

Comment: Yes, I'd expect it to be - but there's no sense in doing the work multiple times. It's not really clear exactly what the issue is yet, but it sounds like really the ball is in your court to do more diagnostic work - we can't help you at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

`pdf_final[i].length` can exceed `pdf_split.length` if your initial string is big enough. To be more exact: when `string_to_split.length()/SIZE > SIZE`.

Im sorry above answer is not true. It could be that `i` gets out of bound and not `j` for big files.

Like Jon Skeet said the statement doesn't give you an array of size 1495:

```
pdf_split = tmp.split("\\r?\\n")
```

Comment: Yes i know. The problem is that i cannot create an array the same size as the pdf_split string, java simply doesn't allow me, he says the max is 1495, that's why i had to divide the original strings between multiple arrays.

Comment: @RJA: "he says the max is 1495" - no, Java is entirely capable of creating larger arrays. What exactly did you try, and what happened?

Comment: @Jon: String[] pdf_split = new String[string_to_split.length()];
        
         pdf_split = string_to_split.split("\\r?\\n");                                               but when i print the size, it gives me 1496. So my full pdf isn't being passed to the array

Comment: ok, something is wierd. The pdf size is acutally the same has the string to split, however, when i'm walking through the array with a for, it only goes up to 1496 and i have no idea why.

Comment: Why create an array and then immediately ignore it? Just use `String[] pdf_split = string_to_split.split("...");`. It sounds like you need to do some more diagnostic work though.